# After derivng a test statistc using p-value combination method, what is the associat null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, combining-p-values

First I generate two one-sided p-values from independent samples using null hypothesis $H_0: \Delta\leq0$, so that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are generated. Next, I apply the inverse normal combination function $T=\sqrt{w_1}\Theta(1-p_1)+\sqrt{w_2}\Theta(1-p_2)$ with weights $w_1$ and $w_2$ which fulfil $w_1+w_2=1$.

What would the associated null hypothesis be? $H_0$:No effect in the overall population, or no effect in neither of the samples?

Answer (score 1):

The null hypothesis is that the $p_i$ all have a uniform distribution on the unit interval.

For more details and a discussion of the alternative hypotheses see [Test for significant excess of significant p-values across multiple comparisons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171742/test-for-significant-excess-of-significant-p-values-across-multiple-comparisons/246059#246059)