# How to interpret the harmonic mean p-value?

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, combining-p-values

I am working on a multiple comparisons problem for several hypothesis tests and have come across the [harmonic mean $p$-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean_p-value) (HMP) for combining the $p$-value of these tests. Specifically, I am using a two-sample $t$-test to compare means of several samples.

Extending the interpretation of a standard $p$-value, is the HMP interpreted as the probability of obtaining test results at least as extreme as the observation given that *every* null hypothesis is correct? In other words, does HMP suggest the amount of evidence that at least one null hypothesis is false? Or is there another interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

The null hypothesis is that all the $p$-values are drawn from a uniform distribution on the unit interval. I have outlined the alternative hypotheses in this answer
[Test for significant excess of significant p-values across multiple comparisons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171742/test-for-significant-excess-of-significant-p-values-across-multiple-comparisons/246059#246059)

You would have to experiment to see if the harmonic p method is one which is best against the alternative that the signal is concentrated in one experiment or across all of them.